# Would I go to prison for killing the neighbor's dog if it attacked me?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, self-defense

My neighbors have a wild dog, they are aware of that hence they put a sign which says "beware of the dog." I try to avoid it but presently there are roadworks near my house so I have to pass by the dog.

Sooner or later it will attack me and I might kill it.  Would I go to prison for that?

Comment: Since you're in the UK, by what means do you imagine you might defend yourself?  My understanding is that almost any lethal weapon is illegal to carry.

Comment: @feetwet I won't be carrying any weapon of course! I am not pre-planning to kill it but if it attacks me I'll grab and brick and smash its head

Comment: @feetwet if [this guy](http://www.fieldandstream.com/blogs/field-notes/2013/05/shepherd-strangles-brown-bear-save-flock-bosnia) could strangle a bear, I suppose OP could strangle a dog.  No weapon necessary.

Comment: @phoog the bear had no owner thus no human laws involved

Comment: @NewAlexandria Sure.  I'm commenting on the necessity of having a weapon, which, in the UK, would be breaking a law even before a hypothetical attack (says feetwet).  My point is that the bear incident implies that it is possible to kill a dog without first having to violate a law prohibiting weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer and I have never even been to the UK.

You will not go to prison if your neighbor's dog attacks you and it dies as a result of you defending yourself.

You might go to prison and/or owe the owner damages if:

- You are somewhere you do not technically have a right to be.
- It can be shown you could have retreated from harm but chose instead to stand your ground.
- The force you used was deemed excessive - it showed intent to harm the dog more than necessary to protect yourself
- You contributed to the confrontation in a way that a reasonable person would think might cause trouble

You might be able to protect yourself from problems by:

- taking pictures or videos of the dog behaving badly or aggressively
- note dates and times when you observe the dog behaving badly or aggressively
- formally contact the dog's owner with your concerns and/or evidence in which you assert your rights to access the areas you walk through and your right to defend yourself in the event that you are attacked by the dog
- if possible, change your route or schedule to avoid the problem entirely

Good luck

Comment: Avoiding a publicly-accessible/owned corridor because of another person's actions (uncontrolled animal) can constitute material damage by that person.  So "change your route" has other implications and I would leave it out.